# Аннотация Enum в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, типы-данных, аннотации

У меня есть функция генерации sql запроса создания enum-а в postgres на основе enum-а в python.

```
def sql_query_enum_creation_get(python_enum) -> str:
   sql_query = ", ".join([f"'{enum_element_key.value}'" for enum_element_key in python_enum])
   return sql_query
```

Хочу сделать аннотацию типов, но при попытке `python_enum: enum.Enum` пишет, что ожидался тип `collections.Iterable`, однако при `python_enum: Union[Enum1, Enum2...EnumX]` всё работает.

Объявление EnumX:

```
@enum.unique
class EnumX(enum.Enum):
    enum_item1_name = enum_item1_value
    .....
```

Почему наследники класса, который не поддерживает итерации, поддерживают её, если я нигде не объявляю их поведение при итерациях?

Как мне создать аннотацию одним типом EnumX, потому что у меня достаточно много enum-ов и перечислять их через Union не особо круто, т.к. функция поддерживает все enum-ы

Answer (score 0):

После просмотра кода в модуле `enum`, я пришел к выводу что аннотацию нужно создавать как `python_enum: enum.EnumMeta`. И это заработало. Я мало знаком с мета классами и буду благодарен, если вы объясните почему я должен указывать в аннотации именно мета класс